# Salvar conteúdo no próprio celular

Tags: android, cache, sharedpreferences, inputstream

Estou fazendo uma aplicação, onde eu tenho uma lista de perguntas, e se caso o usuário sair da aplicação ou da tela, eu gostaria de salvar as questões que ele já respondeu, para quando ele voltar a acessar aquele formulário, as questões respondidas estarão salvas na memória.

Para fazer isso, qual seria a melhor opção, `SharedPreferences` ou `InputStrem`?

Comment: Eu acredito que a melhor opção é o bando de dados local, SQLITE

Comment: Mas é que eu não queria guardar tudo, porque o formulário vai estar incompleto, só depois que eu guardasse toda a informação, ou seja, que o usuário respondesse todo o formulário ai eu guardaria no sqlite.

Comment: E não há a opção de guardar o formulário conforme vai sendo respondido no SQLite? Quando o usuário finalizar o questionário, atribua "FINALIZADO" à um campo da estrutura questionário.

Comment: Utilizando SharedPreferences o Android estará gravando em Sqlite. A diferença é que quem controla é ele não você. Quantos questionários distintos terminados ou em progresso você poderia ter? SharedPreferences não serve a esses casos. InputStream?? Não tem a função que você me pareceu atribuir a ele.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que armazenar dados em SharedPreferences não é uma boa idéia. Em vez disso, salve o progresso em um banco de dados local, SQLite. Ai quando logar novamente é só trazer o que já foi respondido.